# viewDidUnload not called for alloc/init initialized viewcontroller with no xib file

Tags: ios, memory-management, viewdidunload, memory-warning

Why isn't `viewDidUnload` method called, when I'm not using xib and use alloc/init to initialize my `ViewController` when i simulate memory warning for any iOS version via Simulator? It seems as if this method is never called.

If I create controller via alloc/initWithNibName with xib file, viewDidUnload method successfully called.
Why does it happend? Does xib file is reqired for all viewcontrollers to normal handling of memory warnings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve my problem.
My implementation with no xib just need to add this code:

```
- (void) loadView {
   UIView * myView = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
   self.view = myView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`viewDidUnload` is called whenever a memory warning is received and its called for each view controller that has a non visible view, such as a `UINavigationController` if you push a new view controller and this view controller causes memory shortage the presenting view controller  `viewDidUnload` will be called (because its view is not visible)

Also note that if you implement `didReceiveMemoryWarning` and do not call `[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];`, your `viewDidUnload` does not get called

For example if you have in your view controller this

```
- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    //with 
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; // viewDidUnload gets called

    //without [super didReceiveMemoryWarning]; viewDidUnload does not get called
}
```

Comment: Im not overriding didReceiveMemoryWarning method and viewDidUnload still not called.

Comment: is the view  controller that you want to recieve viewDidUnload still visible on the screen? if yes, then it will not receive it

Comment: sure it's not visible on screen, i pop-out from this controller

Answer (score 0):

Constrained by the terms of the beta program, I believe that we're precluded from being able to discuss iOS 6 Beta in any detail, but I might also suggest that you review the bottom of page 6 in the 8 page iOS 6 Beta 1 release notes regarding viewWillUnload and viewDidUnLoad.