# When to use strong or weak for properties

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, declared-property

I have a table view as an `IBOutlet`, and by default XCode sets its property to be `strong` rather than `weak`. Sometimes I get a "recieved memory warning" message. So I tried to change many properties from `strong` to `weak`, but it doesn't seem to affect the process and things work smoothly. Should I set the outlets to weak, or am I wrong?

And most importantly, should I set **ALL** properties to `nil` in the `viewDidUnload` method, or only the `IBOutlet`s?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should IBOutlets be strong or weak under ARC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678469/should-iboutlets-be-strong-or-weak-under-arc)

Answer (score 1):

You should set only `Strong` properties to `nil` in `viewDidUnload`. `Weak` Properties are automatically set to Nil if the destination object is deallocated.

`IBOutlet` can be set to `strong` or `weak` based on the requirement.

For the warning issue you are facing can you provide more details and code?

Apart from link provided by Josh, there are a lot of posts on SO related to this topic, some are below:

[weak or strong for IBOutlet and other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11168916/weak-or-strong-for-iboutlet-and-other)

[Objective-C declared @property attributes (nonatomic, copy, strong, weak)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9859719/xcode-property-attributes-nonatomic-copy-strong-weak)

Good detailed explanation can be found here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

Apple docs on this topic can be found here:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH17-SW1

Comment: I'm using ARC and it automatically sets weak pointers to nil in the viewDidUnload method. and I recieve memory warning.l, although I set all pointers to nil in the viewDidUnload. I put an NSLog there, but instead of calling viewDidUnload it gets low on memory, doesn't release anything (since NSLog isn't shown) and the program crashes. ehat should I do? any suggestions?

Comment: What version of iOS are you using? Not sure why `viewDidUnload` is not being called on low memory warning. Can you post some code here and talk a bit about app, scene, controllers etc? Here's a link that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11050384/viewdidunload-not-called-for-alloc-init-initialized-viewcontroller-with-no-xib-f   **FYI**: `viewDidUnload` is being Deprecated in iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

"When a parent has a reference to a child object, you should use a strong reference. When a child has a reference to its parent object, you should use a weak reference"

In general weak references are used when you deal with memory cycles. if you use strong you need to set nil in viewDidUnload since if you don't do it, in memory low conditions, you could cause unexpected leaks. You don't release them in dealloc because ARC will do it for you. 
weak instead doesn't need that treatment since, when the target object is destroyed, those values are set as nil automatically. No dangling pointers anymore.